# Ruby on Mac OS X 10.9.2

Tags: ruby

I'm using mac os x 10.9.2 ruby 2.1.1 and rbenv. I installed the gems to the ruby version under rbenv. The rbenv shell and local are set to 2.1.1. But for some reason I can't run my code.

Here is the error:

```
/Users/chadd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/formula-1.0.0/lib/formula.rb:8:in 
`<module:Formula>': undefined method `mattr_accessor' for Formula:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Here is the code:

```
require 'formula'

class OpenmwBullet < Formula
  homepage 'http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/'
  url 'http://bullet.googlecode.com/files/bullet-2.82-r2704.tgz'
  ...
```

Here is the trace:

```
from /Users/chadd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/formula-1.0.0/lib/formula.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/chadd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /Users/chadd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/chadd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from openmw-bullet.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: is that a gem i have to install?

Answer (score 0):

`Formula` is a `Rails` form helper that generates awesome markup. The project lets users create semantically beautiful forms without introducing too much syntax.

It is Rails specific gem. You can only use it within a Rails application.

In order to use it.

Install rails `gem install rails`

Follow the steps given in [Getting Started With Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

To access `gem formula`, you'll have to add it to the `yourappname/Gemfile`.
and then run `bundle install`.

Comment: so is rails an independent thing? Can I set rbenv to rails?

Comment: Yes, rails is another gem which is a MVC framework used for web application development. Read Rails Guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Ok I have rails installed. Still isn't working. I'm trying to install this : https://github.com/OpenMW/homebrew-openmw. I get the error even in rib when I try to: require 'formula'